# Most effective approach to building universal iOS apps

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm new to Objective-C and am building my first universal app. So far my design has been optimized for an iPhone 5, but I would like to also optimize for iPad and the original iPhone. From a high level, what is the most effective approach to building a "responsive" interface for iOS apps?

Comment: As an example of something that needs fixing, you can check out my broken UIScrollView: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115957/ios-autolayout-breaks-uiscrollview-pagination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends from your app's design. Generally you can make resizeable views which will look correct on all devices. But since the iPad screen is much bigger than iPhone it's not a good idea.
So the best practice will be making a resizeable interface for all iPhone devices and another one with completely different design for iPad devices (and don't forget about iPad with Retina screen).

Comment: If you image contains something which will look bad when stretched then go for separate xib

Comment: It's not about images only but about the whole look of your app. What looks good on the small iPhone probably will not look so on the iPad.

Comment: You can just use two xibs separate for iPone and iPad. You don't actually need the two complete view controllers with xibs. This will be better option for image resolutions and the complete UI.